# Why Dumper output is not evaluated correcty?

Tags: perl, eval

I try to `eval` output of `Dumper` for pretty simple hashref, where two keys have same value (ref to another hash):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $foo = { data => 1 };
my $boo = {
  x => $foo,
  y => $foo,
};

my $VAR1;
my $bar = eval( Dumper( $boo ) );

print Dumper( $boo );
print Dumper( $bar );
```

I expect the `$boo` and `$bar` to have same structure, but eval seems not solve inner-ref `$VAR1->{'x'}` correctly, I hoped last 2 lines to print same string:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'x' => {
                   'data' => 1
                 },
          'y' => $VAR1->{'x'}
        };
```

But second has `x` or `y` undefined (depending which was referenced in literal form):

```
$VAR1 = {
          'x' => {
                   'data' => 1
                 },
          'y' => undef
        };
```

I tried [simple usage](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html#EXAMPLES) part on doc, and it gave fine results with much more complex structure (`no strict`, yet), but I can' accomplish it with my data with 2 references to same hash.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The assignment to `$VAR1` is the last thing that happens in your eval statement. At the time when the rhs expression is evaluated, `$VAR1` is not yet defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To correctly capture references inside a structure, you need to set the `Purity` flag (see the [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper) documentation for details).

```
$Data::Dumper::Purity = 1;
```

It's not enough, though, as `Dumper($boo)` will now return

```perl
$VAR1 = {
          'y' => {
                   'data' => 1
                 },
          'x' => {}
        };
$VAR1->{'x'} = $VAR1->{'y'};
```

So, you can't just `eval` this string, you also need to return `$VAR1` from it.

To prevent the purity flag interfering with other parts of the code, you can set it locally:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $foo = { data => 1 };
my $boo = {
    x => $foo,
    y => $foo,
};

my $VAR1;
my $bar = do {
    local $Data::Dumper::Purity = 1;
    eval Dumper( $boo );
    $VAR1
};

print Dumper( $boo );
print Dumper( $bar );
```